# Allow text input although InputType of EditText is ClassText

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-inputtype

I set the InputType of my `EditText` control to `ClassNumber` so that when showing the keyboard it has numbers only. But on the Android scanner device there is a hardware button for activating the barcode scanner which should read letters too. Because of `InputType.ClassNumber` the barcode scanner only reads numbers. Is there any way to make it read letters despite `InputType` is restricted to numbers only?

Comment: " InputType.ClassText " is a common type ，it supports all input including numbers and letters .So are you sure you are setting “InputType.ClassText” not “InputType.ClassNumber” 
?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Of course I meant ClassNumber :)

Comment: it only supports number, if you want to support letters,you could use the common type "InputType.ClassText ",or you could add "android:digits" attribute